# mock function that is called inside react component render function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

First of all I want to let know that I am new to testing with react and want to verify if I am writing the right tests.

I have a React Component something like this -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class DemoComponent extends Component
{
    returnSomething()
    {
       return "something";
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <div>{ this.returnSomething() }</div>
        );
    }
}
```

and I am writing to test to verify method calls something like this -

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import DemoComponent from "./DemoComponent.js";

const component = shallow(<DemoComponent/>); 

test('"returnSomething" method is called when the component is rendered', () => {
    component.instance().returnSomething= jest.fn();
    component.update();
    component.instance().render();
    expect(component.instance().returnSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The test runs ok but I want to know if the test I have written is the correct way.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to test a component like this and not using enzyme and snapshot? https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/testing-a-react-redux-app-using-jest-and-enzyme-b349324803a9

Comment: I am using `enzyme`. I have posted just a portion of the code. May be I should update the code for convenience. @AndreasKöberle

Comment: Still why you dont use it in the test? 
`expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()` would test the result of the render method. You are aware of the snapshot feature in jest?

Comment: Yes I am aware of it. I am new to react testing.... still learning step by step. I will surely give it a try after I under its workings.

Comment: .....after I understand its workings.. @AndreasKöberle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were able to write a test here that passes, so I don't see a problem.

Just testing that some method on the component was called doesn't really tell you anything about the result of `render()` - how the component renders. As Andreas points out, testing a snapshot of the `render()` is probably better (assuming you're using Jest) - that way you're testing the actual render results and not just checking whether some method got called during render. Alternatively you could use something like `.matchesElement()` or check for individual properties to create a stronger test.

Comment: Yeah I looked into the snapshot tests and they are pretty worth it. My test assertions have improved after using `snapshots`.